# I do not know what ".com/?c=f25a9a5f951d" means

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, aliexpress

I have a ecomm (wordpress and woocommerce/aliexpress) website.  For some reason, that I cannot find an answer to, every URL appends this parameter "?c=f25a9a5f951d" (actually there are two different ones but answering one should do the trick). I know that ?v=hash is for location but what is ?c=hash mean? Has anyone experienced this?

If so, I need some insight into:
1. what does it mean?
2. why is it appearing? 
3. how do I remove it or can should I?

website is https://poppyandmia.com

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a `GET` variable (i.e. the variable is `c` and `f25a9a5f951d` is its value). It is used to "transport" a certain value from one page to the next one (for example an item ID) and can be read out with PHP like `$my_value = $_GET['c'];`

Comment: Thank Johannes ... unfortunately I know that much but what I really want to know is what is generating this value in the first place?  I thought it might be Chrome but it appears in all the browsers I tested it in.